# Why does make execute a command I never write in makefile and how to debug it?

Tags: c, makefile

Here is the makefile from a unity tutorial with a little change:

```
CLEANUP = del /F /Q
TARGET_EXTENSION=exe

.PHONY: test

PATHU = unity/src
PATHS = src
PATHT = test
PATHB = build
PATHD = build/depends
PATHO = build/objs
PATHR = build/results

BUILD_PATHS = $(PATHB) $(PATHD) $(PATHO) $(PATHR)

SRCT = $(wildcard $(PATHT)/*.c)

COMPILE=gcc -c
LINK=gcc
DEPEND=gcc -MM -MG -MF
CFLAGS=-I. -I$(PATHU) -I$(PATHS) -DTEST

RESULTS = $(patsubst $(PATHT)/Test%.c,$(PATHR)/Test%.txt,$(SRCT) )

PASSED = `grep -s PASS $(PATHR)*.txt`
FAIL = `grep -s FAIL $(PATHR)*.txt`
IGNORE = `grep -s IGNORE $(PATHR)*.txt`

test: $(BUILD_PATHS) $(RESULTS)
    @echo "-----------------------\nIGNORES:\n-----------------------"
    @echo "$(IGNORE)"
    @echo "-----------------------\nFAILURES:\n-----------------------"
    @echo "$(FAIL)"
    @echo "-----------------------\nPASSED:\n-----------------------"
    @echo "$(PASSED)"
    @echo "\nDONE"

$(PATHR)/%.txt: $(PATHB)/%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION)
    #echo gen result
    -./$< > $@ 2>&1

$(PATHB)/Test%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION): $(PATHO)/Test%.o $(PATHO)/%.o $(PATHU)/unity.o #$(PATHD)/Test%.d
    #echo link
    $(LINK) -o $@ $^

$(PATHO)/%.o:: $(PATHT)/%.c
    #echo compile test
    $(COMPILE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(PATHO)/%.o:: $(PATHS)/%.c
    #echo compile src
    $(COMPILE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(PATHO)/%.o:: $(PATHU)/%.c $(PATHU)/%.h
    #echo compile unity
    $(COMPILE) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(PATHD)/%.d:: $(PATHT)/%.c
    #echo gen depend
    $(DEPEND) $@ $<
```

Use mingw32-make to make, it throws this error:

```
D:\test\make\sampleproj>mingw32-make
cc -I. -Iunity/src -Isrc -DTEST   -c -o unity/src/unity.o unity/src/unity.c
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc -I. -Iunity/src -Isrc -DTEST -c -o unity/src/unity.o unity/src/unity.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2):
<builtin>: recipe for target 'unity/src/unity.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [unity/src/unity.o] Error 2
```

`mingw32-make --debug=b` gives this:

```
Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'test' does not exist.
   File 'build/results/Testproduct.txt' does not exist.
    File 'build/Testproduct.exe' does not exist.
     File 'unity/src/unity.o' does not exist.
    Must remake target 'unity/src/unity.o'.
cc -I. -Iunity/src -Isrc -DTEST   -c -o unity/src/unity.o unity/src/unity.c

(A same error message)
```

I can't find where the "cc" command comes from. Adding an echo before each command makes no difference. What's wrong with the makefile? Or how to preprocess the makefile so that it can expand all the variables and wildcards?

Comment: `make` has default rules for many files. For `.c` files, the default rule is to use `cc`. I'm not sure why your rules are ignored, though. IMO, `make` is about as useful as assembly - unsuitable for humans. Use something more sane, like `cmake`, to generate Makefiles.

Comment: Your Makefile weirdly seems to mix Windows `cmd` commands with Unix shell script. The backticks happen to work, but probably not like you imagined; and anyway, that's a really wicked [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score 1):

Because of this rule:

```
$(PATHB)/Test%.$(TARGET_EXTENSION): $(PATHO)/Test%.o $(PATHO)/%.o $(PATHU)/unity.o #$(PATHD)/Test%.d
```

make tries to build `$(PATHU)/unity.o`. You don't have a rule for .o files under `$(PATHU)`, so it falls back to using its implicit rule for .o files: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html. This uses the implicit variable `$(CC)` as the compiler, which defaults to `cc`.

Presumably that rule is meant to list `$(PATHO)/unity.o` as a prerequisite instead of `$(PATHU)/unity.o`.

Answer (score 0):

*make* for each platform comes with a set of default rules for the most commonly used actions - apparently, your make has "cc" as part of those (which is pretty common).

There might be different ways around this:

1. Maybe you're just using the wrong instance of make - try to use the one that came with your compiler (if it did). On one of my systems, the `make` for Mingw is called "Mingw32-make"
2. You can override the default rules by specifying your own in the Makefile with a rule looking like

   ```
   .c.o:
      gcc -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $<
   ```